# The best way to Update the database table through a pyspark job

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a spark job that gets data from multiple sources and aggregates into one table. The job should update the table only if there is new data.

One approach I could think of is to fetch the data from the existing table, and compare with the new data that comes in. The comparison happens in the spark layer.

I was wondering if there is any better way to compare, that can improve the comparison performance.

Please let me know if anyone has a suggestion on this.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: You could also write the new data into a temporary table then use Bigquery [Merge](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax?hl=en#merge_statement) to update the target table.

Comment: The answer is going to be opinion based. Please check out what I have done in my project

Answer (score 1):

> One approach I could think of is to fetch the data from the existing
>   table, and compare with the new data that comes in

IMHO entire data compare to load new data is not performant.

***Option 1:***

Instead you can create [google-bigquery](/questions/tagged/google-bigquery) partition table and create a partition column to load the data and also while loading new data you can check whether the new data has same partition column. 
Hitting partition level data in hive or bigquery is more useful/efficient  than selecting entire data and comparing in spark.

Same is applicable for hive as well.

see this [Creating partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_partitioned_tables)
or 
[Creating and using integer range partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions)

---

***Option 2:***

Another alternative is with [GOOGLE bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax?hl=en#merge_statement) we have merge statement, if your requirement is to merge the data with out comparision, then you can go ahead with ***MERGE statement*** .. see doc link below
[A MERGE statement is a DML statement that can combine `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` operations into a single statement and perform the operations atomically.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax?hl=en#merge_statement)
[image]

Using this, We can get performance improvement because all three operations (INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE) are performed in one pass. We do not need to write an individual statement to update changes in the target table.

Comment: Thank you, Ram. Even if I partition the table by time timestamp, I will run into the same problem, right? For instance, I create the table today, and I update the table with today's data. When the job is run tomorrow, and if it is the same data, wouldn't the data be still copied to the table except for that it will be in a different partition. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect here. Thanks!

Comment: may not be time stamp based partition some other thing like category (for example). by checking the catergory item if its not present you can load the data... otherwise you can ignore the new data... some thing like this....  by doing this basically you are not comparing all the data with all categories with new one. you will be comparing single category item( single partition columnonly ) by not loading all data in to spark memory to compare..

Comment: Thanks much, Ram. Let me try out this idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this problem can be solved, one of the less expensive, performant and scalable way is to use a datastore on the file system to determine true new data.

1. As data comes in for the 1st time write it to 2 places - database and to a file (say in s3). If data is already on the database then you need to initialize the local/s3 file with table data.
2. As data comes in 2nd time onwards, check if it is new based its presence on local/s3 file.
3. Mark delta data as new or updated.  Export this to database as insert or update.

As time goes by this file will get bigger and bigger. Define a date range beyond which updated data won’t be coming. Regularly truncate this file to keep data within that time range. 
You can also bucket and partition this data. You can use deltalake to maintain it too.

One downside is that whenever database is updated this file may need to be updated based on relevant data is being Changed or not. You can maintain a marker on the database table to signify sync date. Index that column too. Read changed records based on this column and update the file/deltalake.

This way your sparl app will be less dependent on a database. The database operations are not very scalable so keeping them away from critical path is better

Answer (score -1):

Shouldnt you have a last update time in you DB? The approach you are using doesnt sound scalable so if you had a way to set update time to each row in the table it will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Ilya. The new data that is read into the spark job is coming in from multiple sources. There is no timestamp. I can add the update timestamp in the table I am creating, but I will still have to read the data and compare. right?  The job can be run and it can still see the same data that it saw yesterday, for instance. Please correct me if I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: Hi if you dont have timestamp data.... you can use anytother thing as partition column to query data. reading partition wise - compare is better than reading entire data to compare. pls see my answer